# Return a value in a cell if the correspondent cell from another column is part of another specific value Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter, openxlsx

I have an excel sheet with 6 columns.
I want to read that file and add another column where to insert a specific text if another specific text is found as a part of a cell on another column.

I have tried:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

#writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testx.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
#writer.save()



#from openpyxl import load_workbook
file = 'testx.xlsx'
#book = load_workbook(file)
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine = 'openpyxl')
#writer.book = book
df = pd.read_excel('testx.xlsx')
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testx.xlsx')
df['Brand'] = df['Keyword'].map({'o.p.1.':33, 'sebastian':'seb', 'd.p.i':34})
df.to_excel('testx.xlsx')
#writer.save()


workbook  = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'testx.xlsx'

writer.save()
#writer.close()
#delete_files()
```

But something is always wrong..

Ex output needed:
I have A-F columns populated and I need the G column to be auto-populated

[image]

z   image_count x   Extracted content   Keyword L_brand Brand
Z1  2   x    Po , Po ,      N
Z2  1   x    D.P.I NAIL LACQUER VERNIS A ONGLES D.P.I NAIL LACQUER VERNIS A ONGLES  d.p.i, p.i, d.p.i, p.i, ,   Y
Z3  1   x    O.P.1 NAIL LACQUER VERNIS A ONGLES O.P.1 NAIL LACQUER VERNIS A ONGLES  o.p.1, o.p, o.p.1, ,    Y

If I use writer I won't get the errors, but it will retrieve a blank sheet

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


file = 'testx.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testx.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df['Keyword'] = df['Brand'].map({'o.p.1.':33, 'sebastian':'seb', 'd.p.i':34})
df.to_excel('testx.xlsx')
writer.save()
```

The edited code from above doesn't throw an error anymore but after loading, when I want to open the excel file it says that has an error and it has to recover as much as it can and retrieves a blank sheet..

Comment: Can you include an example of the csv input file  in your question>  Please post the data in a format that can be copied and pasted by the SO community

Comment: I have post the data from my xlsx file. Now you can copy paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given data its look like your `Keyword` column containing multiple string value while you mapping it with a single value.

In this case, rather than using `map` function we can use the `apply` function with the user definition

So here

```py
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('testx.xlsx')

key_maps = {'o.p.1.':33, 'sebastian':'seb', 'd.p.i':34} # include all 600 combination here 
# I am assuming all keys are in string format 

def myFunc(x):
    key = False
    for word in str(x).split(','):
       if word in key_maps.keys():
           key = True
           break
    return key_maps[word] if key else ""


df['Brand'] = df['Keyword'].apply(myFunc)

df.to_excel('test_result.xlsx')
```

Comment: I got this error in myFunc
    if 'o.p.1' in x:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

But the thing is I need a solution for 600 combinations, the example was including only 3, but I need many more

Comment: Does your keyword column contain float values?

Comment: import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


file = 'testx.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testx.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

key_maps = {'o.p.1.':33, 'sebastian':'seb', 'd.p.i':34} 

def myFunc(x):
    key = False
    for word in str(x).split(','):
       if word in key_maps.keys():
           key = True
           break
    return key_maps[word] if key else ""


df['Brand'] = df['Keyword'].apply(myFunc)

df.to_excel('testx.xlsx')
writer.save()

Comment: it returns a xlsx that needs to be repaired, and after it gets repaired it's blank

Comment: you are overwriting same file my lead you to damage the file which recovers with a blank sheet .. plz refer updated code